# Multiple DialogFragment event callbacks - how do I tell which fragment to update?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-lifecycle

Here is my situation. I have a fragment which has two buttons on it. When you tap on either button, a `DialogFragment` appears which contains a single `EditText` with ok/cancel buttons. Both buttons open the same `DialogFragment`, but the data input into the `EditText`s needs to be kept separate.

I recently started implementing the fragment event callback pattern from the Android docs [seen here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks), but have run into an issue - I have two buttons using the same event callback and am not sure how to differentiate which one the user has just finished using. So using the docs as an example, I can open `FragmentA` from two buttons on the same screen, but need to handle the result differently depending on which button I clicked.

In my fragment:

```
public static class FragmentA extends DialogFragment {
  public interface OnEditNameListener {
    public void onPositiveButtonClicked(String newName);
  }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context){
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mListener = (OnEditNameListener ) context;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement OnEditNameListener ");
    }
}
```

In my Activity, which implements the OnEditNameListener:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    (new EditNameDialog.Builder())
      .setTitle(getContext().getString(R.string.title))
      .setValue(currentText)
      .show(mParentFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
       }
    });

button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    (new EditNameDialog.Builder())
      .setTitle(getContext().getString(R.string.title2))
      .setValue(currentText2)
      .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
      .show(mParentFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
      }
  });

@Override
public void onPositiveButtonClicked(String newName) {
  ... //does stuff with the name. 
//Currently no way to determine whether this came from button1 or button2.
}
```

Currently, both callbacks hit the same OnPositiveButtonClicked method with the input from the `DialogFragment`, but I do not know how to determine which of the two buttons this came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to add an argument to your `onPositiveButtonClicked(String name,int buttonId)`,and the pass to FragmentA an argument based on the button pressed like:

```
FragmentA fragment=new FragmentA();
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
 args.putInt("buttonId", 1 or 2);
 fragment.setArguments(args);
//open the fragment from the activity
```

Then in your FragmentA `onCreate` method try:

```
 int buttonId = getArguments().getInt("buttonId");
```

and finally when positive button pressed call:

```
onPositiveButtonClicked(newName,buttonId)
```

**UPDATE**

An even better solution is to create a setter in your DialogFragment and use anonymus interfaces like:

```
(new EditNameDialog.Builder())
      .setTitle(getContext().getString(R.string.title))
      .setValue(currentText).setOnEditNameListener(new EditNameListener{
         @Override
          onPositiveButtonClicked(String newName){
          //handle action
          }
});
```

And in your DialogFragment add the setter:

```
EditNameListener listener;
public DialogFragment setOnEditNameListener(EditNameListener listener){
   this.listener=listener;
 return this;
}
```

Comment: Went with something similar to your original response. I can't use your update in my case - that's what I originally had. I'm dealing with some edge cases where the activity may have been destroyed but the fragment is still on screen. Only really happens with low memory phones. You can test it out by turning on "don't keep activities" in developer settings on the device. Open up a DialogFragment attached to an activity, leave the app, return to it, then try to close the dialogfragment. Should throw a nullpointer since the listener is gone. Event callback (link in OP) handles this case.